# PHP .htaccess with 3 sub level category

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` settings.

Original URL:
http://localhost/badar/products.php?category=vehicles&product=bus

Rewritten URL:
http://localhost/badar/products/vehicles/bus.php

`.htaccess` code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.php$ /products.php?category=$1&product=$2 [L]
```

When I tried to run the rules and open the URL: `http://localhost/products/vehicles/bus.php` , I got error: `Object not found!`

Is there something wrong with that `.htaccess` code? Or something missing?

And I want to hide `.php` extension so it will be like this:

```
http://localhost/products/vehicles/bus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> RewriteRule ^products/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$
>   products.php?category=$1&product=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

Use `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)` for alphanumeric, `([0-9]+)` for numeric, such as IDs; or use the exact name, such as `products`.

Comment: Hi, I tried your code, but it still `Object not found`, I have an almost answer with this: `RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/d]+)/?$ products.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]` but it only work until this `http://localhost/products/vehicles/`, what I need is: `http://localhost/products/vehicles/bus`

Comment: So you'll just need to add the extra level category, like so: `RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/d]+)/([^/d]+)/?$ products.php?category=$1&category2=$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Pefect... Cheers

Comment: question, why some url value show me `object not found`, example: `http://localhost/badar/products/produkterbaru/CT0002` it show me `object not found`, `http://localhost/badar/products/terbaru/CT0002` it show me correctly

Comment: Can you paste the RewriteRule for those URLs?

Comment: I got it now :), I add your code Rewrite rule `([A-Za-z0-9-]+)`